"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" when adding a group member to Azure AD group via Terraform
Using terraform, we are creating azurerm_mssql_server with SystemAssigned identity and all goes fine. We also try to add it's identity to an existing AD group but it fails.
Here is the terraform block that fails.
resource "azuread_group_member" "my_sql_member" {
  group_object_id  = data.azuread_group.my_sql_group.object_id
  member_object_id = azurerm_mssql_server.sql_servers.identity.principal_id
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "~> 2.48"
    }
  }
  required_version = "~> 1.0"
}

Here is the error that it reports.
azuread_group_member.my_sql_member: Creating...

Error: Adding group member "6c1g53s8-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" to group "09g3jk75-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"

  with azuread_group_member.my_sql_member,
  on resource.tf line 43, in resource "azuread_group_member" "my_sql_member":
  43: resource "azuread_group_member" "my_sql_member" {

GroupsClient.BaseClient.Post(): unexpected status 403 with OData error:
Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the
operation.

We run our code via a pipeline using Azure Service Principal to connect with Azure AD and based on terraform documentation we already added below Microsoft Graph permissions and more but still no luck.
Microsoft Graph (permissions screenshot)

Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy
Directory.AccessAsUser.All
Directory.Read.All
Group.Create
Group.ReadWrite.All
User.Read

I have been given suggestions to basically open all access, but I am looking for some help with narrowing down what exact permissions we need to get this working please.

The documentation mention Group.ReadWrite.All or Directory.ReadWrite.All when using a service principal. Have you tried with Directory.ReadWrite.All as well?

Hi @RuiJarimba, thank you for your comment, no we didn't try Directory.ReadWrite.All as we may not get an approval for such high level permissions, hence was looking for something more specific. We however did try the suggestion Architect Jamie made below and there are some extra findings there.

The permission you need to assign is:

GroupMember.ReadWrite.All

Group.ReadWrite.All allows you to CRUD groups, not group members.

Hi @ArchitectJamie, thank you for your suggestion, we tried adding GroupMember.ReadWrite.All but it did not help in our case unfortunately. Investigating the issue further, we found that our target AD group has a role assigned to it and MS docs suggest "To add members to a role-assignable group, the caller must also be assigned the RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory permission." which is also a very high level permission hence we are now taking it up with our security team to discuss further.

@user24363215 You shouldn't need RoleManagement permission from the context of the code. You will need that on your account, or an admin account in order to assign permission to the account which runs the code to get it set up, but not to add the member in code. Please ensure `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All' is assigned to the identity used by the pipeline, or identity you are using to run terraform.

Thank you @ArchitectJamie as suggested, we already added GroupMember.ReadWrite.All to the SP pipeline uses to authenticate with Azure/AD and our code runs within the context of that SP. Since setting up the pipeline SP is a landing zones / pipeline set up work, we added a task to make our pipeline SP one of the owners of target group it needs to add new SQL identities to and it has resolved our problem for now. Thank you again for sharing your suggestions, much appreciated.
